# Proof of orientation-reversing isometries and their general form

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

Show that each orientation-reversing isometry has the form

$\bar f(z)=c+e^{i\theta}\bar z$, which becomes

$\bar g(z)=ce^{-i(\theta/2)}+\bar z$ after rotation of axes and

$\bar h(z)==\alpha+\bar z$, where $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, after translation of O.

I don't understand even where to start, I don't understand orientation-reversaing isometries, and I don't understand the significance of "$==$"

Comment: Possible duplicate of : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144549/isometry-of-mathbb-r2-that-preserves-orientation-is-either-a-rotation-or-a-t?rq=1